# Unable to install Ubuntu OS

Tags: 18.04, windows, asus

I am having an Asus R541Uv. I tried to install Ubuntu by formatting Windows OS, but unable to process it didn't even come out the disk format option.

[image: System Information]

Comment: Please [edit] and include the info missing along with a better explanation of what you're doing.

Comment: What are you installing from? A live CD? A jump drive?  Are you able to boot from the installation device? If so, how far do you get in the installation process before it stops?

Comment: And I also noticed you tagged the question with 14.04. That release is out of support now, please don't try installing it. Use 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS or the current non-LTS release.

Comment: You have attached screenshot of Windows system properties which I think is completely irrelevant here. This might be useful if you were installing Ubuntu app from MS Store. Also, please [edit] your post and include the screenshots or details where you stuck, what you expect and what's happening.